# perl multiline search and replace

Tags: perl, replace

I need to match and replace a block of code in a file. These are the contents of the file:

```
"56799f8d5282" Cleartext-Password := "56799f8d5282"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN100

"1ee1c3b88cef" Cleartext-Password := "1ee1c3b88cef"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN200

"test1" Cleartext-Password := "password1"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN300
```

Need to search for the block belonging to mac="1ee1c3b88cef" and comment out that block by adding # at the start of each line. The final contents should look like this:

```
"56799f8d5282" Cleartext-Password := "56799f8d5282"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN100

#"1ee1c3b88cef" Cleartext-Password := "1ee1c3b88cef"
#    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
#    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
#    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN200

"test1" Cleartext-Password := "password1"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN300
```

I'm using `perl -0777pe 's/A/B/' /etc/freeradius/users >> /etc/freeradius/users` command to inplace replace the content. But some special character in above block is not matching my command and it's not working.

Comment: Not on all lines. Just match the particular multiline block and add `#` at the start of that block. There are other such entries as well in the file which I don't want to touch.

Answer (score 1):

Using paragraph mode would work great here. A paragraph is a block of text followed by one or more blank lines or EOF. This mode is activated using `local $/ = "";`, or `-00` on the command line.

```sh
perl -00pe's/^(?=.)/#/mg if /^"1ee1c3b88cef"/'
```

The above can be read as follows: If the paragraph starts with `"1ee1c3b88cef"`, prepend `#` to each non-blank line.

---

Note that using `-i` is the proper way to do in-place editing.

```sh
perl -00pe's/^(?=.)/#/mg if /^"1ee1c3b88cef"/' -i /etc/freeradius/users
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [range](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators) instead of messing with multi-line matching and replacement is easy:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/^(?=.)/#/ if /^"1ee1c3b88cef"/ .. /^\Z/' /etc/freeradius/users
"56799f8d5282" Cleartext-Password := "56799f8d5282"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN100

#"1ee1c3b88cef" Cleartext-Password := "1ee1c3b88cef"
#    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
#    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
#    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN200

"test1" Cleartext-Password := "password1"
    Tunnel-Type = VLAN,
    Tunnel-Medium-type = 6,
    Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = VLAN300
```

Adds a `#` to the start of every non-blank line between and including the one starting with that string to the next blank line.

Add `-i` if you want to modify the file in place.